# Compose files must be of the same version | ECS CLI | Docker Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

I am new to ECS CLI and Docker.

Currently, I want to deploy a dotnet app to ECS via the CLI.
I am aware that ECS CLI only support docker `version 3`, thus has changed the docker-compose file version from 3.4 to 3 than ran `docker-compose up --build`

```
version: '3'

services:
  application.api.gateway:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}applicationapigateway
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Application.API.Gateway/Dockerfile

  application.webapi:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}applicationwebapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Application.WebAPI/Dockerfile
```

However, when I try to deploy using `ecs-cli compose --project-name test-project service up --cluster-config test-config --ecs-profile test-profile` the error as below:

```
time="2021-09-29T15:22:50+10:00" level=error msg="Unable to open ECS Compose Project" error="Compose files must be of the same version. Found: 3 and 3.4"
time="2021-09-29T15:22:50+10:00" level=fatal msg="Unable to create and read ECS Compose Project" error="Compose files must be of the same version. Found: 3 and 3.4"
```

Where do I also need to update the dockerfile/docker-compose version?

Other files,

dockerignore

```
**/.classpath
**/.dockerignore
**/.env
**/.git
**/.gitignore
**/.project
**/.settings
**/.toolstarget
**/.vs
**/.vscode
**/*.*proj.user
**/*.dbmdl
**/*.jfm
**/azds.yaml
**/bin
**/charts
**/docker-compose*
**/Dockerfile*
**/node_modules
**/npm-debug.log
**/obj
**/secrets.dev.yaml
**/values.dev.yaml
LICENSE
README.md
```

Comment: Do you have also a docker-compose.override.yml file?

Comment: Does your compose file works with classic docker-compose?

Comment: @ddegasperi , no there is no override file but a dockerignore file. Refer above for it. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the environment variable `COMPOSE_FILE` set?

Comment: Thanks the problem was solve as I didn't update the `docker-compose.override`. Thank you.